# Anyone tried using boost::serialization with boost::geometry::rtree?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, mpi, boost-geometry

I am using boost::mpi with boost::geometry and would like to broadcast a boost::geometry rtree index. The easy workaround is to build the index on each node, but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has a solution. I know there is some non-boost::serialization support in boost::geometry for serializing indices. Perhaps that could be combined with boost::mpi somehow. Serialization would also be nice for dumping/loading state, although again, I could rebuild the index each time if I have to. Thanks.

Comment: Browsing the boost github, I see: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/13fdbb4a7de0e945f54c20988a8441aa2749f26b/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/serialization.hpp

Answer (score 2):

Seems it is desired but not completed. https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/issues/859

Comment: Nice excavation. Thanks for doing the work!